# How to fix the sidebar sub menu items overflowing when large list items in the parent menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side menu bar which has submenus displaying on hover it's children items. Submenus might have multiple children items, that are overflowing beneath the footer div. As you can see in the Attached photo the last child in the sub-menu is under the footer and not well displayed

```
$('.page-sidebar-menu').children('li').hover(function() {
    var posTop = $(this).position().top;
    var liHeight = winHeight - posTop;
    liHeight = $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').offset().top + $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').height();
    console.log("liHeight: " + liHeight + "<br> WinTotHeight : " +  WinTotHeight);

    if (liHeight > WinTotHeight) {
        if ($(this).children('.sub-menu').children().length > 7) {
            $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').attr("style", "top: auto;bottom: -221%;position: absolute;height: 50vh;overflow-y: auto;");
            if($(this).children('ul.sub-menu').siblings().length == 1) {
                var dHtml = "<div class='cloneEle'> <i class=" + $(this).children(':eq(0)').find('i').attr('class') +" style='padding-left:5px;padding-right: 18px;'></i>" + $(this).children(':eq(0)').find('span.title').text() + "</div>";   
                $(dHtml).insertBefore($(this).children('ul.sub-menu'));
                $('.cloneEle').attr('style', 'z-index: 9999999;background: #d54635;padding: 10px;top: auto;bottom: 562%;position: absolute;left: 46px;width: 22.7vw;color: #fff;display:block;');
            } else {}
        }
    } else {}
});
```

The screen shot of my problem
[image: image01].

[image: Image02]

[Working Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/WebTechie/pen/PXodEv?editors=1010)

Comment: Actually, I am not getting what's the issue can you provide codepen or any working URL? other than what I assume you can use bottom:0 (at line #9) for the submenus which are at the end

Comment: @Umer bin Siddique, pls check my latest edit, codepen link added.

Comment: I have reviewed your code.Please add sub menu bottom:0,should not provide minus value.incase of submenu items length is very high,use scroll on it.

Comment: @iyyappan Scrolling and bottom: 0 added for submenu window. But the menu items are hiding if I hover menus located at top.
https://codepen.io/WebTechie/pen/PXodEv?editors=0010

Comment: will it work for you? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBNmwN?editors=0110

Comment: @Umer bin Siddique, it is not giving me the result as I expected.